# What process controls two-finger zoom on Mac?

Tags: bash, mac, touchpad

Every once in a while, plugging my Mac into my monitor when lots of processes are running will crash some of the display agents, like exposé, zoom and other trackpad functions. I figured out some bash commands to kill relevant processes (Dock, com.apple.Dock.agent) to restore every mission control function, but not zoom. Which process controls the two finger zoom, so that I can reset it without restarting my Mac?

Comment: I'm not sure the answer will matter, but out of curiosity, are you talking about pinch/unpinch zoom within apps, or Ctrl-scroll zoom of the whole screen (the Accessibility feature)?

Comment: Pinch/unzoom with apps. The accessibility feature seems more resilient — it's never actually crashed for me — though I rarely use it so maybe it crashes when I don't realize

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad and com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad aren't processes, they are preference files and they can be modified with the `defaults` tool.

I've managed to change the setting from true to false according to `defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad` but this didn't actually disable pinch to zoom or show up in preferences. Changes probably need a restart, or to know which process to kill before making the changes.

The github Pinch app might be your best bet.

Here are the commands that came in handy.

```
$ man defaults
$ defaults find pinch
$ defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad
$ defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad
$ defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad TrackpadPinch -bool false
$ defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad TrackpadPinch -bool true
```

Helpful resources:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/UserPreferences.html

https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/edit-property-lists-apda49a1bb2-577e-4721-8f25-ffc0836f6997/mac

According to the readme doc from the handy app "Pinch" which fixes the pinch gesture, the command that worked for the author is `killall Dock` which isn't working in your case.
https://github.com/danqing/Pinch

Note this comment about using System Preferences to reset it:

> Since I shared the app, it came to my attention that the command
> doesn't work for everyone. So I updated the app to toggle on/off the
> preference in addition. I hope this is a reliable enough fix. If not,
> please let me know by opening an issue or reaching out on Twitter! You
> can check out the discussions here for more info.

I assume you want to use this in a script. Here is the toggle preferences function in the Swift code

```swift
    func toggleTrackpad(mode: Bool) {
        let app = "com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad" as CFString
        CFPreferencesSetAppValue("TrackpadPinch" as CFString, mode ? kCFBooleanTrue : kCFBooleanFalse, app)
        CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(app)
        GestureHandler.sharedInstance().setTwoFingerPinch(mode)
    }
```

OLD:

> That seems to suggest that your trackpad service is responsible for
>  the pinch setting. You could try to kill it and restart it in one line
>  with  `killall com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad ! && com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad &`
>
> This won't toggle the setting, but give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Beautiful. I'll try that when it breaks again

Comment: Unfortunately it errors: CFString not found in scope